# Web forum table layout

Tags: html, html-table

I have a question regarding using table structure for a web forum.

[image: picture of layout]

I know how to make the individual cells for everything, I am just unsure how to make the table layout properly.

```
      <table>
            <tr>
             <td>
              <fieldset>
               <legend>Personal Information</legend>
                <p>
                  Text field 1 <input type="text" name="entry1" id="entry1"   /> text box default size = 20
                  <br />  
                  Text field 2 <input size="30" name="entry2" id="entry2" /> 
                  <br />  
                  Text field 3 <input size="5" maxlength="5" name="entry3" id="entry3" />
                  <br />  
                  Text field 4 <input size="12" value="416-" name="entry4" id="entry4" />
                </p>
              </fieldset> 
              <h4><mark></fieldset></mark></h4>
             </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
             <td>
             </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          </form>
```

This is how I think I will use the various boxes. Any help on how to set up the 3 columns (table structure)  so it will have a layout like in the image above would be greatly appreciated. Just to be a bit more clear..... how to get the structure to have the paps pizza and phone number/cost in the 1 column, then have the personal info, cheeses etc in the 2nd column then have the image in the 3rd column.

Comment: You should use tables just for data, and in cases like yours you should use divs and css. Ever heard about bootstrap?

Comment: Tables should not be used for layout purposes. They should only be used when you have tabular data to render. For layout, you should use CSS.

Comment: how would you structure the layout so it would look as above then?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)

Answer (score 0):

The following is just one way to do layout with CSS. A more modern approach is with flex-box (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), but flex-box is more sophisticated.

You can place whatever content you need to into each `<div>`, which acts like a column when it's floated or the footer, when it's not.

```css
#col1, #col2, #col3 {float:left; border:1px solid #000;box-sizing:border-box;}
#col1 {width:20%;}
#col2, #col3 {width:40%;}
#footer {clear:both; background:#000; color:#fff;}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <div id="col1">column 1</div>
  <div id="col2">column 2</div>
  <div id="col3">column 3</div>
  <div id="footer">footer</div>
  
</div>
```